# Getting SchemaMismatchException

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

This is my first app with Realm ObjC. I have defined a model like

```
@interface Token : RLMObject
@property NSInteger identifier;
@property NSString *refreshToken;
@property NSString *scope;
@property NSString *tokenType;
@property NSString *accessToken;
@property double expiresIn;


+ (instancetype)modelObjectWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation;
- (BOOL) isExpired;
@end
```

When I run

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```

to save my Token object, an exception breakpoint is triggered at

```
throw SchemaMismatchException(errors);
```

Comment: try to delete the app and reinstall and see if the problem gone

Comment: Thanks @Tj3n, it worked!

Comment: it wont completely solve your problem, this is just work around, what actual you need to do is bump your schema version

Answer (score 1):

You got the problem because you change the model class (like add or delete property), after that, you must either:

- Delete the app and reinstall it, will affect people who already
  installed the app
- Bump your Realm's schema version and/or do migration if needed, as described in [Realm's document, Defining
  Migrations](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/), basically, add this
  into your AppDelegate or where you create Realm config:

  ```
  RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
  config.schemaVersion = 1;
  [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
  ```